# Is 'developer' tab in Reports now a deprecated feature?

Tags: civireport

In Civicrm 5.4 and in current version in WP Sandbox, it seems that the 'Developer' tab is no longer shown. What is the replacement/suggested method for adding a column to reports now?

Answer (score 3):

To view developer tab for the report the user will need 'CiviReport: view report sql' permission. This is new permission added in recent version of CiviCRM for broader access control.

You can set permission by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control) >> WordPress Access Control

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: This user is an Administrator (this is a WP site). Don't administrators by default have all perms?  How do I set/select this permission, in current ACL settings this isn't clear to me.Thanks.

Comment: I am an administrator and I am not seeing developer tab; in the WP sandbox (https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/) when I login as admin, I also don't see developer tabs in reports.

Comment: The demo user on the wordpress sandbox does not actually have all admin permissions. In your own wordpress if you are a higher level admin you will see these settings at https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

Comment: You need to add permission for each role. The demo user don't have above permission hence you were not able to see the developer tab. I have updated my answer on how you can set permission

Comment: In this case, I am an Administrator, and while Wordpress Access Control section lists all particular permission for the roles for Author, Contributor, etc., the text does say that Admins have all perms ("NOTE: Super Admin and Administrator roles will have all permissions in CiviCRM.") and doesn't list Administrator at all for specific permissions.  thanks anyway.

Comment: I do see 'Civicrm Administrator' listed in the sandbox, and when I enable the permission I do see the Developer tab, so it is something about the way my Admin is set up I guess!

Comment: In Permissions.php, the role 'administrator' is not displayed; but the new perm is not granted, apparently. I temporarily commented-out the 'if admin..', checked the permission for Review Report SQL, and now I see the Developer tab.  When this perm was added, it seems it didn't default to allowing administrator.